# Does Flex require PHP framework?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, adobe

I am new to Flex and have written code in PHP before, but not used any PHP framework like Zend, CakePHP etc...

I plan to use Flex with PHP, for that do I need to use any MVC PHP framework? Do any of the frameworks integrate with Flex for the View?

Answer (score 1):

Although no framework is strictly needed, it can be very helpful. This might help you get started: [Flex/PHP framework download](http://blogs.adobe.com/mikepotter/2006/06/download_a_flex.html) and Zend's [Flex and PHP](http://devzone.zend.com/article/2019). (Google is your friend)

Answer (score 1):

Flex is a client side technology and is completely loose from the serverside technology.

You can use PHP for exposing webservices but just as well java or asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Flex does not require a framework, you could work without. However, using a framework will make it a lot easier, especially for big projects.

Answer (score 0):

A framework is not required but using one will greatly improve your productivity.
You can start looking at the flex tutorials on [this site](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/index).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily connect your Flex app to a PHP backend simply by outputting your php query results as XML, Flex can read that XML with an HTTPService with resultformat = e4x.

No frameworks required and it's super simple to do.

Hope it all works out for you.